# How to use laply match to lookup value and append in each row?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two data tables as below:

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), date = as.Date(c("2015-5-26","2015-6-15","2015-4-03","2015-5-26","2015-6-15","2015-4-03","2015-5-26","2015-6-15","2015-4-03","2015-5-26","2015-6-15","2015-4-03")))
y <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4),new_id=c(10,20,30,40))
```

As mentioned now I want to append the new_id column in the data table x and then later drop column id .

I can do this by

```
merge(x,y,by="id")
```

But I wanted to try the lapply .

So I tried

```
x[,new_id:=0]
nm <- c("new_id")
x[nm] <- lapply(nm, function(z) y[[z]][match(y$id, x$id)])
```

Also which method will be good if I have wide columns and more rows.

It does not matches the column it seems.

Also which method will be efficient if I have wide columns and more rows.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are using `match`, then you don't need `lapply` i.e. `y$new_id[match(x$id, y$id)]`

Comment: I guess you are just looking for an update join: `x[, new_id := y[x, on=.(id), x.id]]` the x.* prefix refers to the x table's columns in j of `x[i,on=, j]`